# Python random number loop with different outcomes each time

Tags: python

I’ve been working on a school project and need to do a loop consisting of a couple random numbers but I need them to output a different number each time. The code I’ve been using for the random numbers is this.

import random

a=random.randint(1,9)

I’m new to coding and just starting getting into python for fun and have looked everywhere for how to complete this loop but I can’t find anything that works.I know this code does not include a loop and the loop I was using before was “while True” and “for i in range”  Thanks

Comment: That's a statement not a loop. You should look into how to make a `for` loop or a `while` loop in python and then try to put the random number portion inside of it.

Comment: Loops are one of the most fundemental concepts in any programming language. I would recommend reading up on the fundementals.

Answer (score 1):

You have not created any loop yet. You're generating random integer only once.
In order to generate more of them you have to use something like a `for` loop.

If you're familiar with the concept of `range` then this is a simple example of generating x-number of random integers.

```
import random

x = 10
for i in range(0, x):
    a = random.randint(1, 9)
    print(a)
```

Comment: I understand I haven’t added a loop and I don’t think I was really clear sorry I’m looking to get a random number after multiple equations for example having 2 of the random number lines add to 1 integer and randomizing all of that so the last integer is also random every thim

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are doing something like this.  Your loop needs to call the random.randint function on each iteration of the loop.

```
a = random.randint(1,9)

for i in range(5):
    print(a)
```

What you should be doing is this

```
for i in range(5):
    print(random.randint(1,9))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have 5 values between 1 - 9 without repetition you can use the sample function of the random module. This will select n values from a list and store them in a new list.

```
array = random.sample(range(1, 9), 5)
for elem in array: 
    print(elem)
```

But if you want to have a new random value between 1 and 9 every iteration and you dont care if a number is repeated I would go with the answers the others already gave you.

Answer (score -2):

Random works with a seed, with the same seed the same output

Easiest way to achieve that you want, you will have a different seed each time you run your program

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
random.seed(datetime.now())
for _ in range(10):
    a=random.randint(1,9)
```

Comment: There is no need for a seed here. Besides, you are overriding the variable `a` every iteration.

Comment: True, but since it's a school project, not a bad thing to learn how the things you use work but it was maybe a bit too in depth so I get your point, it overrides 'a' but maybe he wants to do something with it after in the loop. But I do agree with you I would recommand to reading up on the fundementals too !